# I want to generate SAS URL dynamically via C# code for Azure Blob Container. Using this SAS URL we must be able to upload the files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I want to generate SAS URL dynamically via C# code for Azure Blob Container. Using this SAS URL we must be able to upload the files to the Azure Blob Container. I have tried multiple ways to generate the SAS URL by following the Microsoft docs. But I am always getting AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch Error or AuthorizationPermissionMismatch.

Error: `AuthorizationPermissionMismatch` This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

```
private static Uri GetServiceSasUriForContainer(BlobContainerClient containerClient,
                                          string storedPolicyName = null)
        {
            // Check whether this BlobContainerClient object has been authorized with Shared Key.
            if (containerClient.CanGenerateSasUri)
            {
                // Create a SAS token that's valid for one hour.
                BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
                {
                    BlobContainerName = containerClient.Name,
                    Resource = "c"
                };

                if (storedPolicyName == null)
                {
                    sasBuilder.ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
                    sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobContainerSasPermissions.Read);
                }
                else
                {
                    sasBuilder.Identifier = storedPolicyName;
                }

                Uri sasUri = containerClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);
                Console.WriteLine("SAS URI for blob container is: {0}", sasUri);
                Console.WriteLine();

                return sasUri;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"BlobContainerClient must be authorized with Shared Key 
                          credentials to create a service SAS.");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Error: `AuthenticationFailed` Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

I need this sas url because I use this url in my javascript to upload files into the Azure Blob Container.
Can someone help me out achieving this goal?

Comment: I removed the [sas] tag.  Please use tags that are related to your question instead.  Microsoft and Azure products have their own tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you are creating the SAS token with `Read` permission (`BlobContainerSasPermissions.Read`).

In order to upload a blob in a container using SAS URL, the SAS token needs either `Write` (`BlobContainerSasPermissions.Write`) or `Create` (`BlobContainerSasPermissions.Create`) permission. Please create a SAS token with one of these permissions and you should not get this error.

To learn more about the permissions, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#permissions-for-a-directory-container-or-blob.

Comment: After executing BlobContainerClient blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(
                 connectionString: connectionString,
                 blobContainerName: "testing");                 I am getting this below error--> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040). Any idea how to fix this issue currently I am using .net 4.8 framework.

Comment: Please share the name and version of the .Net SDK you’re using.

Comment: .Net 4.8 Framework and From nuget packages I have installed Azure.Storage.blob version 12. Please let me know if you need any more information.